# trouble with adding child node C#

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, nodes

I am adding a child node to the current parent node in treeview. But my problem is that it adds the new node to the end of the current parent rather than to add in the position which the `if` is true.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
   if (action_type1 != action_type2)
   {
      TreeNode new_node = = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[position];
      string new_name = "";
      new_node.Nodes.Add(new_name);
   }
}
```

of course `num`, `position`, `action_type1`, and `action_type2` are variables in my code and for any for loop they are different integers an strings. `action_type1` is the name of nodes of treeView and `action_type2` is a fixed string. `if` loop looks for whole the tree if there is nodes equal with the given string then leave the node otherwise insert an empty node in the tree and then do recursively. 
but to make it simple, let we have:

```
int num = 2;
int position = 4;
string action_type1;
string action_type2;
```

Comment: something is wrong with this piece :    foreach (TreeNode Node in nodes)
   {
       new_node = Node.Nodes[position];
   }

Comment: `num = 0` won't run the loop a single time. There is much missing, which makes it more confusing than it should be I think

Comment: @Saber - what about the foreach? What do you want to happen there? Cause it is non-sense now.

Comment: You should consider using [TreeNodeCollection.Insert Method (Int32, TreeNode)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w99w164.aspx) instead of looping through the *nodes*...

Comment: @Alex you are right. I wrote it in another way. Because by `treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[position]` I could access to the curent parent.

Comment: I think posting the whole actual method will improofe the understanding of the problem much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want?

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
   if (action_type1 != action_type2)
   {
      treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes.Insert(position - 1, virtual_name);
   }
}
```

Comment: I think `Insert(position - 1, new_node)` should be changed into `Insert(position - 1, "")`. Because the scond argument should be a string. right?